# Prevent raising next events in a async event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, task-parallel-library, async-await

When GetDataAsync executed, textBox1_Validating event is raised before textbox1_Leave event finished. how can I do to prevent this situation?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool IsValid = true;

    private async void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Working");

        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        IsValid = await client.CheckUser(textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsValid)
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't (unless you make it synchronous)

Comment: How are you calling these events? Via `TextBox`?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe the `Leave` event isn't the best place for this? Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to do we could help you find another solution.

Comment: @James I changed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`Control.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx):

> events occur in the following order:
>
> 1. Enter
> 2. GotFocus
> 3. Leave
> 4. Validating
> 5. Validated
> 6. LostFocus

When you `await` inside `Control.Leave`, you let the UI message pump continue execution, hence it proccess the next event. If you want to wait until `Leave` finishes, run your method synchronously.

Comment: If I run method synchronously my form freezes until the method finished. it's a bad idea. What can I do?

Comment: You can not run this code from `TextBox` events. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to show a waiting panel when Service is doing it's job.

Comment: Then why set this inside a textbox valudate method? Create a method that notifies the user while work is being done

Comment: I want to show (showdialog) a loading form when service started and hide it when it finished. if I run method synchronously all forms hanged and freezed until method finished.

Answer (score 1):

The `Validating` process of a control is a synchronous process, you can't have it wait until you return from your asynchronous method before continuing. The point of `async` / `await` is to allow the UI continue whilst you wait on the result of your asynchronous method therefore once you `await` inside the `Leave` event the control assumes it's complete and continues on with the rest of the event chain.

The `Validating` event should be used to perform *synchronous* validation, if you need server validation then you just have to accept that the text entered *is* valid and on then `Validated` event you could then send off your request

```
private bool IsValid = false;

private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ValidateUser(textBox1.Text);
}

private async void ValidateUser(string username)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    IsValid = await client.CheckUser(textBox1.Text);
    if (IsValid) {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username, try again!");
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set e.Cancel = true; in Textbox Validating Event.

Comment: @ArMaN well, unfortunately, you can't. I have already explained in my answer why you can't do this.

Comment: @ArMaN my answer will still give you the asynchronousy, it just doesn't use the `Validating` event to do so. If you really want to not block the UI then you need to accept that the `Validating` event isn't the right place to do this.